# Adding values after set comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set comprehension that works perfectly, but i need to add multiple values to that set after the comprehension. 
Add function only takes one argument, and even if only 1 argument is given, it returns None. Update function takes only iterables.

```
def ss(y,z):
    return {x**2 for x in range(y)}.add(y,z)
```

How to achieve such a thing using set comprehension.

Comment: Please check out this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: just trying to help YOU out. Have a good day mate

Comment: A rude response to a comment will not get you much help here. Also, the question is not "blatantly obvious," at least not to me. Please clarify your purpose.

Comment: Sorry, but it's equally rude to me. As if your tire popped on a highway and i sent you to a mechanic instead of helping you change it. 
I've seen questions answered on this site that are far vaguer and poorly worded. Also please don't forget that not everyone is a native speaker. 

And clarification you asked for. return {x**2 for x in range(y)} returns a set of squares of x. I need to return a set of squares and 2 extra values at the end of that set, that are not squares.

Nevermind tho, I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `update` on set or call `add` twice:

```
def ss(y, z):
    result = {x**2 for x in range(y)}
    result.add(y)
    result.add(z)
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you, but i need to do that in set comprehension format.

Comment: Why do you need to?